# Oracle SQL Repeated words in the String

Tags: sql, oracle

I need your suggestions/inputs on of the following task. I have the following table:

```
ID      ID_NAME                             
------ ---------------------------------   
1       TOM HANKS TOM JR                    
2       PETER PATROL PETER JOHN PETER       
3       SAM LIVING                          
4       JOHNSON & JOHNSON INC               
5       DUHGT LLC                              
6       THE POST OF THE OFFICE              
7       TURNING REP WEST                    
8       GEORGE JOHN
```

I Need a SQL query to find a repetitive word for every ID. if it exists, i need to get the count of the repeated word.
For instance in ID 2, the word PETER was repeated 3 times and in ID 1 the word TOM was repeated twice. so I need the output something like this:

```
ID      ID_NAME                             COUNT
------ ---------------------------------    --------
1       TOM HANKS TOM JR                    2
2       PETER PATROL PETER JOHN PETER       3
3       SAM LIVING                          0
4       JOHNSON & JOHNSON INC               2
5       DUHGT LLC                           0    
6       THE POST OF THE OFFICE              2
7       TURNING REP WEST                    0
8       GEORGE JOHN                         0
```

Just an FYI, The table has 560K rows

I tried the below and it didn't work and it is literally looking for every single word.

```
SELECT RESULT, COUNT(*)
    FROM (SELECT
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(COL_NAME, '[^ ]+', 1, COLUMN_VALUE) RESULT
          FROM TABLE_NAME T ,
               TABLE(CAST(MULTISET(SELECT DISTINCT LEVEL
                                   FROM TABLE_NAME X
              CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(X.COL_NAME) - LENGTH(REPLACE(X.COL_NAME, ' ', '')) + 1
                                  ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST)) T1
          )
   WHERE RESULT IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY RESULT
   ORDER BY 1;
```

Please let me know your inputs.

Comment: Hi Kumar,  -  to get your tables and code formatted, what you did was excellent, but there's one more step - you need to select the text and press Ctrl-K, or the little  { }  icon at the top. Please remember for future postings.

Comment: Take a look at   REGEXP_COUNT function.

Comment: What if there is more than one repeated word?

Comment: Also, how do you define "word"? Does JOHN appear twice in `'JOHN PAUL FINCH AND JOHN-PAUL SMITH'`?

Comment: Yes In the above Text String John should appear twice

Comment: What about mathguy's question? What if the string was `BOB G SMITH AND BOB J SMITH`? What would you expect the result to be - 4?

Comment: So I see BOB repeated twice & SMITH repeated twice, doesn't matter as long as it pulled the record for review. 2 or 4 should be fine

Comment: Wait - do you want the count, or do you just want to `SELECT` the rows where the string has at least one repeated word? These are two very different problems with different solutions, even though they seem related; the latter is much simpler than the former.

Comment: Also, the query can be easily modified to show you ALL the distinct words that appear at least twice in the input string, and the count for each one of them. This is an easy modification of what I posted. Just decide with your business folks exactly what they need.

Comment: Count is secondary. All I needed is the list of names with repeated words.

Comment: OK, I will add to my answer to show how you can get just the rows where there is at least one repeated "word".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next solution find first repeted word and in next step find count of repeating. Edit just now to fix extra subword findings

```
with s (ID, ID_NAME) as (
select 1, 'TOM HANKS TOM JR' from dual union all    
select 10, 'TO TOM TOM TOM TOM TO TO TO STOM HANKS TOM TOMMY' from dual union all    
select 2, 'PETER PATROL PETER JOHN PETER' from dual union all
select 3,  'SAM LIVING' from dual union all
select 4,  'qwe JOHNSON & JOHNSON INC' from dual union all
select 5,  'DUHGT LLC' from dual union all
select 6,  'THE POST OF THE OFFICE ' from dual union all
select 7,  'TURNING REP WEST ' from dual union all
select 8,  'GEORGE JOHN ' from dual)
select id,
       case when r1 = 0 then 0
            else regexp_count(id_name, r3)
               - regexp_count(id_name, r3||'\w+')  -- exlude word with tail
               - regexp_count(id_name, '\w+'||r3)  -- exclude words with head
               + regexp_count(id_name, '\w+'||r3||'\w+') -- double calc with head and tail
       end as rep_count
       from (
select
s.*,
regexp_instr(s.id_name, '(^|\s)(\w+)(\s|$)(.*(\2))+') as r1 ,
regexp_replace(s.id_name, '.*?(^|\s)(\w+)(\s)(.*(\s)\2(\s|$))+.*$', '\2') as r3
from s);
```

the result is

```
    ID  REP_COUNT
---------- ----------
     1      2
    10      4
     2      3
     3      0
     4      2
     5      0
     6      2
     7      0
     8      0
```

Answer (score 1):

The query below counts repeated words and returns the highest count (if a word appears three times and another appears twice, the result will be the number 3). It treats `JOHN` as different from `John` (if capitalization shouldn't count as "different" then wrap the input strings within `UPPER(...)`). It only considers space as a word delimiter; if something else, like dash, is also considered as a delimiter, add to the `REGEXP` search pattern. Make sure you put a dash right at the end of a square-bracketed matching character list, etc. - the usual "tricks" for matching character lists. More generally, adapt as needed.

The query first breaks each input string into individual words, and counts how many times each word appears. For the count, I only need the words ("tokens") in the `GROUP BY` clause, I don't need to actually `SELECT` them, this is why the innermost query may look odd if you aren't forewarned. (Now you are!)

It also seems you want to show `null` rather than 1 if there are no repeated words, so I wrote the query to accommodate that. (Not sure why 1 wasn't OK.)

```
with
     test_data ( id, id_name ) as (
       select 1, 'TOM HANKS TOM JR'              from dual union all
       select 2, 'PETER PATROL PETER JOHN PETER' from dual union all
       select 3, 'SAM LIVING'                    from dual union all
       select 4, 'JOHNSON & JOHNSON INC'         from dual union all
       select 5, 'DUHGT LLC'                     from dual union all
       select 6, 'THE POST OF THE OFFICE'        from dual union all
       select 7, 'TURNING REP WEST'              from dual union all
       select 8, 'GEORGE JOHN'                   from dual
     )
--  end of test data; SQL query begins below this line
select id, id_name, case when max(cnt) >= 2 then max(cnt) end as max_count
from (
       select id, id_name, count(*) as cnt
       from   test_data
       connect by level <= 1 + regexp_count(id_name, ' ')
              and prior id = id
              and prior sys_guid() is not null
              group by id, id_name, regexp_substr(id_name, '[^ ]+', 1, level)
     )
group by id, id_name
order by id        -- if needed
;
```

**Output**:

```
ID ID_NAME                        MAX_COUNT
-- ----------------------------- ----------
 1 TOM HANKS TOM JR                       2
 2 PETER PATROL PETER JOHN PETER          3
 3 SAM LIVING
 4 JOHNSON & JOHNSON INC                  2
 5 DUHGT LLC
 6 THE POST OF THE OFFICE                 2
 7 TURNING REP WEST
 8 GEORGE JOHN

8 rows selected.
```

**EDIT**:

If you only need to find the returns where the string column has at least one repeated word, and you don't care what the highest "repeated word count" is or how many words are repeated, the solution is simpler and more efficient; you don't need to split the input string into component words and count them.

(The OP indicated in the comments, after long dialogue, that this would suffice.)

In the solution the "match pattern" in `regexp_like` searches for a string of letters, preceded by either the beginning of the string or a space or a dash and ended by space, comma, period, question mark, exclamation point or dash. Both "markers", for beginning and end of a word, can be modified as needed. Make sure the dash is either the first or last character in `[...]`, anywhere else it has a special meaning.

Then it looks for a repetition of the word. That's what `\2` does in the match pattern. It's 2 and not 1 because the "word" is in the second pair of parentheses; I need the first pair for the alternation, EITHER start-of-string OR (space or dash).

Look at the first and the last string for special situations that this query covers correctly. Think of any other possible situations that the query may or may not cover.

```
with
     test_data ( id, id_name ) as (
       select 1, 'TOM HANKS TOM-ALAN'            from dual union all
       select 2, 'PETER PATROL PETER JOHN PETER' from dual union all
       select 3, 'SAM LIVING'                    from dual union all
       select 4, 'JOHNSON & JOHNSON INC'         from dual union all
       select 5, 'DUHGT LLC'                     from dual union all
       select 6, 'THE POST OF THE OFFICE'        from dual union all
       select 7, 'TURNING REP WEST'              from dual union all
       select 8, 'GEORGE JOHN-JOHN'              from dual
     )
--  end of test data; SQL query begins below this line
select id, id_name
from   test_data
where  regexp_like(id_name, '(^|[ -])([[:alpha:]]+)[ ,.?!-].*\2')
order by id   --   if needed
;

ID  ID_NAME
--  -----------------------------
 1  TOM HANKS TOM-ALAN
 2  PETER PATROL PETER JOHN PETER
 4  JOHNSON & JOHNSON INC
 6  THE POST OF THE OFFICE
 8  GEORGE JOHN-JOHN
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have 560K rows in the table that needs to be checked. so do I need to prepare a 560K union SQL with all values ?

Comment: No, you don't. Wherever in my solution (which is everything below the commented line) I have a table name or a column name, my query refers to the `test_data` "table" I created in the WITH clause. Replace those with your actual table and column names, instead of referring to the table `test_data`.

Comment: @mathguy, can you try making `MAX_COUNT` to zero if there are no duplicates in the `ID_NAME` column?

Comment: @MigsIsip - yes, easily - `max_count` is defined through a `case` expression where I left out the `else` clause (by default, if you omit it the value assigned is `null`). You can add `else 0` before the word `end`. But that would be inconsistent with the rest of the table; why 0 and not 1?